# Photos, faces and order

Tags: photos.app

I have two Macs with the Photo app and sync over iCloud.

I have tagged a lot of faces in both (I know they are not synchronised so I had to do it twice).

In one version the persons which are present in more photos are placed at the beginning and have a bigger "circle", on the other Mac all the "circles" have the same size and appear in random order.

It is possible to choose how the person are ordered? Is it possible to enable the different sizes also on the second machine?

Comment: You can drag and drop the circles to whatever order you prefer. In my Mac, only the first row has bigger circles.

Comment: Hi, exactly, one one of the machines the first row is bigger, on the other one is not. I do not see how to switch.

Comment: Can't you drag them on the second one?